Excel Autofilter not showing data if a criteria element does not exist in filter
Ive spent days working on this issue and searched many forums for an answer.
I have a table of data which contains 5 columns (Source, Area, message, Incidents, Downtime_Hours):
Data Table

I am trying to display and sort the data via a macro using AutoFilter.
Sub MRS_DIVERTS()
'
' MRS_DIVERTS Macro
'

'
'    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$3000").AutoFilter Field:=2
'    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "U140505*", "U850180*", "U860000*", "U85017*", "U850190*", "U140535*", _
        "U140540*", "U250000*", "U14055*", "U14056*", "U140585_J_LAT", "U14057*", _
        "U14058*", "U14059*", "U14060*", "U14062*", "U140610*", "U14063*", "U140640*"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "*140505*", "*140535*", "*14058*"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW_JAM_DATA").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW_JAM_DATA").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("D1:D3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW_JAM_DATA").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

As long as the criteria element exists in the Source column, everything works fine. When there is an element in the criteria that does not exist in the filtered field, then nothing displays. Not even the good items.
I believe the issue is in error handling, but I can't figure it out.
In this code example, 140535* and 14058 exits in the data, and when I have just those two criteria, it displays/sorts the data just fine. But when I add 140505 into the criteria, then I just get a blank output. 140505 doesn't exist in the filter list.
Can somebody help me figure out a way to display/list/sort the data based on the filter criteria, even if one or more of the filter criteria elements don't exist in the list?
Thank you in advance for looking at this.
I tried adding in criteria elements one by one until it stopped showing the data, which is how I found out that it won't list anything if there is a criteria element that doesn't exist in the filter list.
I've tried implementing error handling capability but unfortunately my knowledge on this subject is very limited and I really have no idea what I'm doing or how to handle it.

You can't filter for more than two wildcard criteria. Look here: Set Auto Filtering multiple wildcards

@Blackcat: Yes - but the result isn't empty because a code is not present but because of the wildcards within the criteria array.

@Ike   Thank you for that information. I knew that there was a maximum of two criteria to use, but I did not know there was a maximum of two wildcard elements in the array. That makes what I'm trying to do almost impossible, unless I list every element as a full, non wildcard tag in the array. And that would be very difficult.  Again, thank you in explaining why my solution won't work. Now I just need to try and figure out a solution that WILL work. Ugh.
